# Can I programmatically change the background color of the touch bar?

Tags: swift, background-color, nstouchbar, macbookpro-touch-bar

Can I change the **background color** of the MacBook Pro touch bar programmatically (**for my macOS app**)?
I am afraid that there is no API for doing that, but I am asking you anyway!

Answer (score -1):

This is the best I can offer you as far as customization goes:

- Add buttons to the Touch Bar within apps
- Add buttons to the Touch Bar Control Strip
- Remove Siri and other buttons from the Touch Bar Control Strip
- Hide the Control Strip completely, maximizing Touch Bar app region
- Hold down the FN key to show Expanded Control Strip, not function keys
- Other transient Touch Bar customizations, hide QuickType typing suggestions

Comment: Sorry, I meant programmatically. I edited my question

Comment: In that case I dont think you will be able to do that with the stock os